# como leer archivos ZW, YG, YG5, en C#?

Tags: c#, unicode

he estado esto luchando por poder leer archivos de tipo **.zw, .yg, .yg5**, entre otros formatos, que son archivos que descargue por medio de usb del lector biometrico de industrias [ANVIS el modelo W1](https://www.anviz.com/page/w1.html).

Dentro de estos archivos **deberían de estar los usuarios y marcajes de los usuarios**, pero cuando trato de abrirlos con cualquier editor de texto este contiene caracteres que no son reconocidos, en sublimetext por ejemplo solo me muestran solo numeros.

**Lo que me muestra sublime: archivo YG**

```
a501 2500 0023 0000 0003 40ff ffff ffff
ffff 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0001 fc00 0040 0000 0003 44ff ffff
ffff ffff 4d61 6d61 6e69 2053 6f74 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0001 fc00 0040 0000 0003 4667
ce02 ffff ffff 5a61 7261 7465 2041 6cc3
a100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0001 fc00 00c0 0000 0003
48ff ffff ffff ffff 50c3 a972 657a 2052
6f64 7200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 fc00 0040 0000
0003 4aff ffff ffff ffff 476f 6d65 7a20
4265 6c74 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 fc00 0040
0000 0003 4cff ffff ffff ffff 4c65 6f6e
2041 6775 6972 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 fc00
0040 0000 0003 4eff ffff ffff ffff 436f
726f 2056 696c 6c63 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
fc00 0040 0000 0003 52ff ffff ffff ffff
5175 696c 6c61 2056 6172 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
... y mas todavia..
```

Estube creado un poco de codigo para poder decodificar estos pero no logro que funcione.

Esta es una imagen de lo que consegui del archivo **BAK.ZW**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otras hay mas suerte y se entiende por lo menos algo. Archivo **YG**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi con el resto. Les dejo los archivos de prueba [aqui archivos de prueba](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gkoc-u5498gauqO5KY-GOEjvcfg2-QdP)

Y el codigo con el cual estoy tratando de hacer que estos archivos sean entendibles:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\archivos\YG");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\t" + ToUnicode(line, 20127));

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static string ToUnicode(string value, int codePage)
        {
            Encoding windows = Encoding.Default;
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            Encoding sp = Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage);
            if (sp != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                byte[] wbytes = windows.GetBytes(value);
                if (windows.CodePage != sp.CodePage)
                {
                    byte[] ubytes = Encoding.Convert(sp, unicode, wbytes);
                    return unicode.GetString(ubytes);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] ubytes = Encoding.Convert(windows, unicode, wbytes);
                    return unicode.GetString(ubytes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

La verdad no entiendo bien lo que estoy haciendo, pero espero que alguien de Stackoverflow se haya tropezado con este problema y ya lo tenga solicionado. espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: alguna ayuda... alguien pls

Comment: Cada fichero contiene la misma información, en diferentes formatos? O son ficheros con diferentes datos? Lo digo porque, de primeras, el único que puedo abrir es el .db, que es una base de datos SQLite

Comment: No es normal que un dispositivo guarde información en la forma mas simple como es el texto plano, claramente si el dispositivo cuenta con una especie de base de datos guardará la información en un formato binario, de ahí que cuando tratas de abrir estor archivos aparezcan solo números... o caracteres raros. Para poder leer el archivo correctamente tendrías que contar con alguna librería especial del fabricante que permita leer ese formato de archivo, de otro modo no hay nada que hacer

Comment: @AlbertoTorre,  son ficheros diferentes, es decir el contenido es diferente

Comment: @JhonnathanQ, no es que sean archivos especiales de fabrica, solo que tienen un formato `unicode`, es una extencion china y tiene caracteres chinos los cuales no se reconocen en nuestro sistema ascii